# Display: block to remove free space between image and button. Why?

Tags: css, asp.net

Why is it that I need to set the `display:` to `Block` on the button and the image to remove the space between them?

**CSS:**

```
#Box {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: green;
    width: 70px;
    height: 100px;
}
#Image1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block; /*???*/
}
#Button1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block; /*???*/
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Box">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

Comment: `display` property changes the way an element would be displayed on the page. Block level elements are rendered into separate lines. An alternative is using a `<br>` line break after the first element which may or may not fit your needs.

Comment: @HashemQolami But how is that related to the space there is between them?
Why isn't it the margin-top on the button, and the margin-bottom on the image that determines whether there is any space or not?

Comment: Ah.. I was under this assumption that you're talking about the white-space between those inline elements. In fact, `margin-top` and `margin-top` **only** works on `block` or `inline-block` elements. Hence in order to get them to work, you probably need to change `display` property of the element.